# InvokeHTTP NIFI TrustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm Trying to send a GET Request to an external API which I need to put an apikey as a header to authenticate .

My problem is when I use the InvokeHTTP Processor with a GET Method and I add an attribute apikey with the key value, I get the following error :

```
The trustanchors parameter must be non-empty



  2016-12-06 20:49:36,007 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP InvokeHTTP[id=d5437c56-0158-1000-f994-28154b2af3ae] Routing to Failure due to exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2016-12-06 20:49:36,009 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:283) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP.onTrigger(InvokeHTTP.java:624) ~[nifi-standard-processors-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1064) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
2016-12-06 20:49:36,359 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP InvokeHTTP[id=d5437c56-0158-1000-f994-28154b2af3ae] Routing to Failure due to exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2016-12-06 20:49:36,360 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:283) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80) ~[okhttp-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP.onTrigger(InvokeHTTP.java:624) ~[nifi-standard-processors-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1064) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Would you please look in your `NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file for a full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Are you connecting to an HTTPS endpoint? If so, you'll need to load a truststore in order to verify the server certificate presented by the endpoint. You can use `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` with the default password of `changeit` for this -- it contains the CA certificates trusted by your installation of Java.

Comment: I updated my post with the full stack trace

Comment: with postman it works with both http and https . I ll try this

Comment: @Andy it worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied suggestion from comments to serve as definitive answer:

> Are you connecting to an HTTPS endpoint? If so, you'll need to load a
>   truststore in order to verify the server certificate presented by the
>   endpoint. You can use `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` with the
>   default password of `changeit` for this -- it contains the CA
>   certificates trusted by your installation of Java.

Comment: How do you load this trust store?